# C# & JS: decimal rounding (positive and negative values)

Tags: javascript, c#, decimal, rounding

For decimal rounding purposes in C# and JS, I have come to use the following functions that seem to work for positive values :

C#

```
public static decimal RoundAwayFromZero(decimal number, int precision)
{
    // default rounding
    return Math.Round(number, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}

public static decimal RoundEven(decimal number, int precision)
{
    // usual bank rounding
    return Math.Round(number, precision, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
}

public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, int precision)
{
    // always round up
    var multiplier = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, precision));
    return Math.Ceiling(number * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

JS

```
function roundAwayFromZero(number, precision) {

    // default rounding
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var n = precision < 0 ? number : 0.01 / factor + number;
    return Math.round(n * factor) / factor;
}

function roundEven(number, precision) {

    // usual bank rounding
    var x = number * Math.pow(10, precision);
    var r = Math.round(x);
    var br = Math.abs(x) % 1 === 0.5 ? (r % 2 === 0 ? r : r - 1) : r;
    return br / Math.pow(10, precision);
}

function roundUp(number, precision) {

    // always round up
    var multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return Math.ceil(number * multiplier) / multiplier;
}
```

Could these adapted functions work for both positive and negative values?

C#

```
public static decimal RoundAwayFromZero(decimal number, int precision)
{
    return Math.Round(number, precision, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
}

public static decimal RoundEven(decimal number, int precision)
{
    return Math.Round(number, precision, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
}

public static decimal RoundUp(decimal number, int precision)
{
    var negativeFactor = number < default(decimal) ? -1 : 1;
    var factor = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Pow(10, precision));
    return negativeFactor * Math.Ceiling(number * negativeFactor * factor) / factor;
}
```

JS

```
function roundAwayFromZero(number, precision) {

    var negativeFactor = number < 0.0 ? -1 : 1;
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var n = precision < 0 ? number : 0.01 / factor + number;
    return negativeFactor * Math.round(n * negativeFactor * factor) / factor;
}

function roundEven(number, precision) {

    var negativeFactor = number < 0.0 ? -1 : 1;
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    var x = number * negativeFactor * factor;
    var r = Math.round(x);
    var br = Math.abs(x) % 1 === 0.5 ? (r % 2 === 0 ? r : r - 1) : r;
    return br * negativeFactor / factor;
}

function roundUp(number, precision) {

    var negativeFactor = number < 0.0 ? -1 : 1;
    var factor = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return negativeFactor * Math.ceil(number * negativeFactor * factor) / factor;
}
```

My tests seem to be convincing, but I prefer to confirm my results here before validating the working of these functions.

Thanks.

Comment: For c# at least, all fiddeling with signs seem completely unnecessary. And "RoundUp" would be typically called "Ceiling" as in "Math.Ceiling", see also "Math.Floor". I'm no JS programmer, but I would expect that there are some math library that provides rounding and other math functions.

Comment: I have simplified the C# and JS methods. I'm not a JS programmer either, I'd still prefer not to have to depend on an additional library for just that.

Comment: Isn't the `Math` library built-in to JS? In which case you can just use `Math.ceil()` and so on.